# How to stream or "pipe" audio in macOS/OSX without file save?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, audio-streaming

I'm going through the docs of [AVAudioRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder) but I still don't really know how to begin streaming audio from the microphone without saving it to file.

Recording from the mic and saving it to a file is straightforward:

```
// swift 3.0

let recorder: AVAudioRecorder;

do {
  recorder = try AVAudioRecorder.init(url: URL, settings: SETTINGS);
  recorder.record();
} catch {}
```

How do I approach this problem? The programming language doesn't matter (i.e. Swift vs Obj-C).